# Require.js Config for Namespace Prefix

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Is there any way to define a path for all modules under a certain namespace in require.js?

Let's say I have the following modules defined:

- *Vendor/Plugin1/MyModule1*
- *Vendor/Plugin1/MyModule2*
- *Vendor/Plugin2/MyModule1*

Now I want to map all modules under *Vendor/Plugin1* to a certain path let's say */plugin1/js/** and all modules under *Vendor/Plugin2* to */plugin2/js/**.

Is this possible with require.js or do I need to define every single module by itself?

Comment: I am not sure, but this look like you have to use https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map

Answer (score 0):

at: `/plugin1/js/newModule`

```js
import Vendor/Plugin1/MyModule1
import Vendor/Plugin1/MyModule1

// organise your modules, like:

const m = {
 ...myModule1, ...myModule2
}

// if you you only want to change the path for some reason, just import modules, then export them.


export m;  // or export default m;
```

the code above shows one example, you need to organise your modules depending on your needs.

you can now, import all your stuff from `/plugin1/js/newModule`